# Why was the `never` type introduced in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have now searched the internet for an explanation of WHY the `never` type was introduced. Both the TypeScript handbook and the TypeScript Deep Dive exaplains what it is and a few other articles. None of them explains, though, WHY you would use the `never` type and what it solves. 
Most of the examples show code, where the compiler already infers `never`, so why do I have to assign the type? What does it solve. Is it “just” to signal the intellisense what I can do afterwards (i.e. Nothing - which might be useful enough). And what do the compiler use the information for? 
As always, explanations of WHAT and HOW might help people do stuff, but only WHY makes them understand.

Answer (score 53):

The `never` type is TypeScript's representation of the [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) from [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory).  So if you are looking for motivation for and uses of `never` in TypeScript, you might want to look into the bottom type in computer science in general.

---

The canonical answer to "why was `never` introduced to TypeScript" is probably best found by analyzing the commentary on [the pull request that introduced it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8652) and the two issues that it addresses: [a request for a bottom type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3076), and [request to better handle unreachable function returns](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8602).

The main use for developers is to have a type for functions (or sections of functions) that don't return any value at all, not even `undefined`.  Compare these functions:

```
function u(): undefined {
    return;
}
const uRet = u();
console.log(typeof uRet); // undefined

function v(): void { }
const vRet = v();
console.log(typeof vRet); // undefined
```

which return `undefined` values, with these functions:

```
function throws(): never {
    throw new Error();
}
const tRet = throws();
console.log(typeof tRet); // does not run

function loops(): never {
    while (true) { }
}
const lRet = loops();
console.log(typeof lRet); // does not run
```

which don't return values at all, due to an exception or an infinite loop.  The `never` type allows both developers and the compiler to reason about sections of code which can never run.

---

There are other uses for `never` but I am not going to try to enumerate them, since you already are aware of code examples.  It is illuminating to examine the [TypeScript standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/v2.7.2/lib) to find the places where `never` shows up.

---

Finally, when you ask

> Most of the examples show code, where the compiler already infers `never`, so why do I have to assign the type?

note that even in cases where the compiler infers `never` for you, it is useful for it to exist in the language, in the same way that `string` is useful even when it is inferred by the compiler.  This seems like a different question about when you might want to explicitly annotate types instead of letting the compiler infer them, and vice versa.  But this post is already long and this is probably answered elsewhere.

Hope that helps; good luck!

---

Edit: There are plenty of reasons a programmer would use `never`, although many programmers might never need to use it.  Let me enumerate some reasons I can think of:

- If you are writing typings for a JavaScript library where a function throws an exception instead of returning, you can't really do that without `never`.
- Generic type parameters default to `{}` when they can't be inferred by the compiler.  It sort of "fails open", since `{}` is compatible with (almost) all values.  There are cases when you'd prefer it to "fail closed" and have it be compatible with no values.  You can use `never` as the default parameter.
- The union of any type `T` with `never` is just `T`, and the intersection of `T` with `never` is `never`.  These rules (among others) let a developer build fairly sophisticated type functions that would be harder or impossible without `never`.  For example, here's `Diff<T,U>`:

  ```
  type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> =
    ({ [P in T]: P } & { [P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];
  ```

  It is a type function which takes a union of string literals `T` and a union of string literals `U`, and returns a union of all the values in `T` which are not present in `U`.

  You can use it to, among other things, remove a property from a type:

  ```
  type Foo = { a: string, b: number, c: boolean };
  type FooWithoutB = Pick<Foo, Diff<keyof Foo, 'b'>>;
  // equivalent to { a: string, c: boolean }
  ```

It's kind of like the number zero in mathematics.  You don't *need* it; many cultures got along okay without the concept of zero.  But it's incredibly useful and allows you to easily express ideas that would otherwise be cumbersome or impossible.

Hopefully that is a little more compelling?  Anyway, good luck again.

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation. So it really says that it is more a compiler need than a programming need, since again, no real reasons for WHY you would use the never statement as a programmer, right?

Comment: There are plenty of reasons a programmer would use `never`.  I've edited my answer with some of them.

Comment: Thanks again jcalz. So it is still more to make complete descriptions of the types of such functions, since a function never returning could still be of type void and work just fine, except it would indicate that the function actually would return void, which it does not since it does not return? And to help the compiler: typescriptlang.org: "The second method uses the never type that the compiler uses to check for exhaustiveness:" So I still do not see any "practical" reasons - solving any real problem, right? Ah  - except it will PREVENT af function from returning that shouldn't?