# Angular - add ngClass on 5th button click

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to add ngClass to a div after a series of 5 button clicks.

Here is the button located on the app.component.html file:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onToggleDetails()">Display Details</button>

<p *ngIf="showSecret">Secret Password = tuna</p>

<div *ngFor="let logItem of log" 
  [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: logItem >= 5 ? 'blue' : 'transparent'}"
  [ngClass]="{'white-text': logItem >= 5}"
>{{ logItem }}</div>
```

Here is the app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'], *** EDIT ***
  styles: [`
  h3 {
    color: dodgerblue;
  }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  username1 = '';
  showSecret = false;
  log = [];
  onToggleDetails(){
  this.showSecret = !this.showSecret;
  this.log.push(this.log.length + 1);
  }
}
```

Here is app.component.css

```
.white-text{
  color: white;
}
```

Currently, the logItem background remains blue after the 5th button click.  I can inspect the console and see that the class .white-text has been added, but the text remains black.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

When I inspect the element, you can see the class has been added:

[image]

I am new to Angular and I am following a udemy course and got stuck here.  I cannot proceed to the next part unless I fix this.

Comment: Select the element in the inspector and check its styles to see if another CSS selector overrides the color set in `.white-text`.

Comment: Check for index of logItem instead

Comment: Before that check with hardcoded value like `5===5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your component definition as per below to include the CSS file.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.cs']
  })
```

Comment: Nice catch, but still no change.  The text is still black.  Any thoughts?

Comment: My bad (oversight) , you can't have both styles and styleUrls. So you will have to move the styles part to css file. Edited my answer as well.

Comment: I think that did the trick.  I commented out styleUrls and added class .white-text to the styles and everything works now.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: I can actually remove styles and just use styleUrls and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

log : any [ ] = [ ];

This was another solution when searching for a more specific question I will give credit where credit is due. [What is "not assignable to parameter of type never" error in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to format it better, like `log : any [] = [];`. And it is better "visually"  if the link encompasses less words, not all the phrase.

Comment: @MarceloScofanoDiniz thank you for your input and the welcoming. Any input to better oneself is always appreciated by those open to it. I appreciate it.