# Suddenly getting typescript errors about type "Never" everywhere

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been working on an app for a while now (Angular 10). I was working on a React project for the last month and didn't touch the angular one. Opened it today and it is riddled with errors. Suddenly, I cannot use the built in array functions on arrays embedded within objects because they aren't typed anywhere so they defaulted to type 'never'.

Here is an example ...

```
  this.currentDesign.parameterMenus.forEach(menu => {
    let thisIndex=menu.parameters.findIndex((mI) =>  { return ss==mI['shapediver']});
    thisIndex !=-1 ? type = 'parameter' : '';
  });
```

The error occurs on the 'parameters' aspect of the menu.parameters array. While the "currentDesign" object has a model and an interface, the parameters array does not. [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript), it just defaults to never instead of any and that is a problem.

The exact error is

```
Property 'parameters' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

Why did this start happening and what can I do about it?

Comment: Did you do changes in `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: No. And I didn't update anything or reinstall node modules

Comment: If you are using vscode, can you check the typescript version from the lower right corner?

Comment: can please you also post the exact error message ? it will help us to understand your problem !

Comment: The typescript version is 4.1.2