# Argument of type '{ type: string; weight: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to display json data in my angular material table but I have a problem I don't understand.

error:
**The type argument '{type: string; weight: number; }' is not assignable to the type parameter 'never'.**

What does type never mean ?

**ts.file**

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  ELEMENT_DATA: Itype[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['dechets.type', 'dechets.weight'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);

  constructor(private typeService: TypeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllDetails();
  }

  public getAllDetails() {
    let resp = this.typeService.getAllType();
    resp.subscribe(resp => {
      this.dataSource.data = resp.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc.push(...item.dechets); // probleme is here
        return acc;
      }, []);
    });
  }
```

**interface**

```
export interface Itype {

    type_collecte: string;
    dechets:
    {
        type: string;
        weight: number
    }[];
    code_traitement: string;
    annee: number;
    mois: number;
}
```

Comment: try defining a type for acc: IType[]

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What is “not assignable to parameter of type never” error in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52423842/8017690)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to collect all the `dechets` arrays from each element of the `resp` array and flatten them, you could use `Array#map` with `Array#flat`.

```js
this.typeService.getAllType().subscribe(resp => {
  this.dataSource.data = resp
    .map(item => item.dechets)
    .flat(1);
});
```