# Angular - error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'never[]' for list of countries

Tags: angular

In my Angular-11 application, I am trying to load list of countries into select option as dropdown. Then display it in user registration:

I have this code in component.ts:

```js
export class SignupCompanyComponent implements OnInit {
  countries = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCountries();
    console.log(this.loadCountries());
  }

  headers = { //Token for API Authorization
    'Authorization': this.token.get(),
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }

  loadCountries() {
    this.api.get('core/fetchCountries', this.headers).subscribe(
      data => this.countries = data,
      error => {
        this.toastr.error(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And component.html is:

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputCountryName">Country</label>
    <select id="inputCoutryName" class="form-control custom-select" formControlName="country_id" placeholder="Country">
      <option selected disabled>Select one</option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of countries" value="{{c.id}}">{{c.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

I got this error:

> error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

> 74         data => this.countries = data,
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Even when I changed

> countries = [];

into

> countries = any;

I got another error:

> error TS2693: 'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

> 43   countries = any;

The api JSON response for countries is like this:

```js
{
  "message": "Countries successfully viewed.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "countries": [{
        "id": 2,
        "capital": "Accra",
        "nationality": "Ghanaian",
        "country_flag": null,
        "currency": null,
        "currency_code": null,
        "currency_sub_unit": null,
        "currency_symbol": null,
        "currency_decimals": null,
        "full_name": null,
        "iso_3166_2": "GH",
        "iso_3166_3": "GHA",
        "name": "Ghana",
        "calling_code": null,
        "created_by": 1,
        "updated_by": 0,
        "created_at": "2021-06-03 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": null,
        "deleted_at": null
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "capital": "Abuja",
        "nationality": "Nigerian",
        "country_flag": null,
        "currency": null,
        "currency_code": null,
        "currency_sub_unit": null,
        "currency_symbol": null,
        "currency_decimals": null,
        "full_name": null,
        "iso_3166_2": "NG",
        "iso_3166_3": "NGN",
        "name": "Nigeria",
        "calling_code": null,
        "created_by": 1,
        "updated_by": 0,
        "created_at": "2021-06-03 00:00:00",
        "updated_at": null,
        "deleted_at": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "not assignable to parameter of type never" error in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the API response, you need to use the `results` value directly on the subscription, you are assigning an object to an array and thats not valid (`data => this.countries = data.results.countries`).

Even better declare the `countries` to the expected custom type.

```
contries: {id: string, ...otherProperty: string}[]= null;
```

For the record, you can also remove this validation on the *tsconfig.json* file, with this two properties:

```
 "noImplicitReturns": false,
 "strictNullChecks":false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable declaration in typescript is like:

```
var [identifier] : [type-annotation] = value ;
```

So in your case try:

```
countries: any[] = [];
```

(var would be not necessary)

Comment: @GaelJ - When I added countries: any[] = [];,   I got this error:  error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?   The this is underlined:   this.countries = data,

Comment: @htp15 Your use of array syntax is very confusing, especially to somebody new to angular or TypeScript. It is unclear if you mean array, tuple, optional value, or entered those square brackets as your way to indicate a placeholder. Please follow conventions and format your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

In your `subscribe` you need to "traverse" the response:

```
this.countries = data.results.countries // according to your example
```

Then type it as an array `countries: any[]` or better define an interface rather than `any`