# How to fix "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'"?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get a new object/type from the other one, but get a `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'` error

```js
const Flags = {
  ONE: () => 'one',
  TWO: () => 'two',
  // ...
};

type createEnumType<T> = {[K in keyof T]: K};
type FlagsObject = createEnumType<typeof Flags>;
type FlagsKeys = keyof FlagsObject;

const keys = Object.keys(Flags) as FlagsKeys[];
let result = {} as FlagsObject;
for (const key of keys) {
  result[key] = key;// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
}

/*
Expected value and type:
result = {
  ONE: "ONE";
  TWO: "TWO";
}
*/
```

I set the type to the `result`, so what am I doing wrong? Why is `never` here?

Comment: Define the array type, otherwise it will be `never`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "not assignable to parameter of type never" error in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

the problem is that the expression `result[key]` has type `never`, which is a type with no values. Let's see why it happens:

- `key` has type `'ONE'|'TWO'`
- `result` has type `{ 'ONE': 'ONE'; 'TWO': 'TWO' }` hence:

  - `result['ONE']` has type `'ONE'`
  - `result['TWO']` has type `'TWO'`
- `result[key]` may sometime be `result['ONE']` and sometimes be `result['TWO']`. If you want to assign something to it you have to choose a value that can be both. No value can be at the same time `'ONE'` and `'TWO'`.

To do what you expect you have to type `key` more strongly but you cannot do that since you have to loop. I suggest you override the typing for `result` inside the loop so that the type is still strong outside:

```
(result as Record<typeof key, typeof key>)[key] = key;
```

Comment: Thank you for the walk-through explanation, it really helped me understand the situation. I know I've read something similar recently (probably on the TypeScript website) but your description cemented it for me today.