# typescript set object key value with a list of possible string

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, object, types

I have an error that I do not understand, I try to set the value of an object for a key and I got the folling error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'`

This is my code

```js
let result: MYOBJECT = {
  "MYKEY": null
}
const key: KeyPossibleValue = "MYKEY" as KeyPossibleValue;
result[key] = "test"
```

What is really strange, this work I do not have the error (it work without the as)

```js
let result: MYOBJECT = {
  "MYKEY": null
}
const key: KeyPossibleValue = "MYKEY";
result[key] = "test"
```

(here I only deleted the as)

I think it's pretty strange since I typed key as KeyPossibleValue from the beginning so the as should be really effective no ?

this is my models:

```js
type KeyPossibleValue = "MYKEY" | "FOO";

type I_MYOBJECT = {
  [key in KeyPossibleValue]?: unknown;
}

interface MYOBJECT extends I_MYOBJECT = {
  "MYKEY": null | string,
  "FOO"?: null | number
}
```

I cannot only let the I_MYOBJECT since multiple key of the object have different value type, but also I want the interface to be based on the possible value of KeyPossibleValue.

Can someone please explain me why does this appear ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: *"it works without the as"* - no [it does not](https://tsplay.dev/wepbVW): *"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'"*

Comment: Yes I correct it, I miss clicked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68075836/how-to-fix-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-never)

Comment: @TobiasS. Yea it does, I had to re-read it again and again to really understand why you cannot do just what I've done but okey I understand now the conflic between the type checking and the multiple possibilities you open (and typescript isn't here to let you do anything)

Comment: But by the way I still do not understand why without as as I do not get this error

Comment: When you don't use `as`, the type of  `key` is `"MYKEY"`. And TypeScript knows that `result["MYKEY"]` is of type `string`. That's why there is no error.