# Typescript forEach "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'"

Tags: typescript

This code gives me "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'" where the comment is made.

```
type serviceInfoType = {
    PORT: number;
    HOST: string;
    MS_NAME: string;
    MS_KEY: string;
};
type serviceInfoParametersType = keyof serviceInfoType;
let serviceInfo = {} as serviceInfoType;
let serviceInfoParameters: Array<serviceInfoParametersType> = [
    "PORT",
    "HOST",
    "MS_NAME",
    "MS_KEY",
];
serviceInfoParameters.forEach((e) => {
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
    serviceInfo[e] = 'something';
});
```

If I change the code to this:

```
serviceInfo[e as string] = 'something';
```

Then it works. But I have no idea why it doesn't work. Can anyone explain why it says type never?

EDIT:

Alex Kolarski made a right call of me trying to assign .env variables (which types I changed).

You can do this (which works and is correct way):

```
if (e === "PORT") serviceInfo[e] = process.env[e];
else if (e === "MICROSERVICE_NAME") serviceInfo[e] = process.env[e];
else serviceInfo[e] = process.env[e];
```

Which is "essentially" this:

```
serviceInfo[e] = process.env[e];
```

Except this doesn't work.

If you don't need anything else but to assign values you are OK with the 'as string' hack. But if you need to do other stuff like changing or checking types of the variables, you should use the correct way.
Because then the intellisense works and TS is happy.

Comment: This sets `PORT` to the value `"something"`, a string, but that property's type is declared as `number`. So you get an error message because the code is logically wrong. For an explanation of the "type `never`" part, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68075836/12299000).

Comment: @kaya3 I made the code simpler. I know i can't assign "something" to number. But thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because TypeScript does not know the type of `serviceInfo[e]`.

If `e` = **"PORT"** the type of `serviceInfo[e]` is `number`

If `e` = **NOT** **"PORT"** the type of `serviceInfo[e]` is `string`

So the type of `serviceInfo[e]` becomes `never` since it cannot be both `string` and `number` at the same time.

So when you have `serviceInfo[e] = 'something'`, TypeScript it is not sure how to type check it, because you are trying to assign a `string` ("**something**") to `serviceInfo[e]` that can be either `string` and `number` and in the case if it is a `number` there should be an error.

`serviceInfo["PORT"] = 'something';` - you are assigning `string` to a `number`.

---

There are several ways to mitigate this.

**Option 1:**
Make sure `serviceInfo[e]` is only one type the type in the forEach like so:

```
serviceInfoParameters.forEach((e) => {
    if (e === "PORT") {
        serviceInfo[e] = 3000;
    } else {
        serviceInfo[e] = 'something';
    }
});
```

This way TypeScript will figure out that if `e` is not `"PORT"` it always defaults to a string.

**Option 2 (not ideal):**
You can make everything in serviceInfoType a string like so:

```
type serviceInfoType = {
    PORT: string;
    HOST: string;
    MS_NAME: string;
    MS_KEY: string;
};
```

Then you will have no issues.

I'm not sure of the goal here, so I cannot provide more context, but it seems to me that you are trying to load **.env file** and in that case it make sense that everything should be a string and type it that way.

Then you can convert it if you need a number.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I added EDIT to my question and upvoted your answer.

Comment: Yeah, all env variables by definition are strings. So the cleanest way for me is to create a type `RawEnvVariables` like so: `type RawEnvVariables = Record<string, string>` and assign your env variables. And then if you wish you can parse it to your custom interface `EnvVariables` where you use `parseInt(..,10)` to convert the env variables to your interface. `const env: EnvVariables = {...myRawVars, PORT: parseInt(myRawVars['PORT'], 10)};`

Comment: I have changed the types of these variables in .d.ts like so: declare global { namespace NodeJS { interface ProcessEnv { ... }}} . Because I didn't want to do this checking and parsing. Which works fine.

Comment: Another note: doing `serviceInfo[e as string] = 'something';` is problematic and can cause you troubles in other cases. In this case since it is a const it might be ok. serviceInfo["PORT"] is a `number` for typescript, but in reality is a `string`. Doing  `serviceInfo["PORT"] + 1` typescript will think that it is adding numbers, but you will be doing concatenation.