# How to declare a complex type and cast data into it?

Tags: typescript, typeerror

*Note: I am starting with TypeScript, coming from a Golang background (and Python - but that does not help for this question*

I am trying to improve my TS code by using type declarations whenever possible. There is however a place I do not know how to approach.

I have the following data (it is currently hard-coded, but will eventually be retrieved through an API as JSON data):

EDIT: following Kelvin's comment, I will be more precise with the actual code, which unfortunately means bringing in a Vue3 artefact

```
// this defines a reactive variable, initialized to an empty Array.
// when looking at the type in my IDE, I see that it is []never
let allEvents = ref([])

// and later on I add some data (please discard the `.value` part, it comes from Vue3, pretend it is not there)

let allEvents.value = [
    {
      start: '2021-07-20T12:55:04.225937+02:00',
      end: '2021-07-20T14:55:04.225937+02:00',
      name: "qqc aujourd'hui",
      id: 'aaa',
      important: false,
    },
    {
      start: '2021-07-21T12:55:04.225937+02:00',
      end: '2021-07-21T14:55:04.225937+02:00',
      name: 'qqc demain',
      id: 'bbb',
      important: false,
    },
  ]
```

This generates errors when compiling my code:

```
ERROR in src/components/googleCalendar.vue:88:11
TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    86 |           end: '2021-07-21T14:55:04.225937+02:00',
    87 |           name: 'qqc demain',
  > 88 |           id: 'bbb',
       |           ^^
    89 |           important: false,
    90 |         },
    91 |       ]
```

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52423842/903011) addressed the `never` aspect and my understanding is that I should somehow declare this structure as an Array of Objects, and then the structure of these Objects.

How should I do that?

In Go I would declare a type (an array of structures), and then cast the data into that type. Is there an equivalent in TS?

Comment: Is that your complete code regarding that variable (assignment)? TypeScript wouldn't complain about assigning the wrong type if you don't specify the type. Your code is missing an important part that's causing this error.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs: your assumption is correct. I wanted to avoid bringing in Vue3 components but this mislead my question, sorry. I edited it.

Comment: Generally, when you initialize an array like `let a = []`, typescript does not know the type of that array, so it infers `never[]` and thinks you can only pass empty arrays. You have to do something like `let a: MyInterface[] = []`

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new variable and initialize it to an empty array, TypeScript sees it as `never[]` because it just doesn't know what to do with it. You can give TypeScript a [hint](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) though of what type it actually is, for example:

```js
interface MyDataObject {
    start: string;
    end: string;
    name: string;
    id: string;
    important: boolean;
}

let allEvents = ref<MyDataObject[]>([]);

// Now this will check whether the given object matches the MyDataObject type
allEvents.push({
    // would complain now because we're missing start/end/name/...
});
```