# How to set object variable inside an array state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript

I have a some state like this :

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState([{id: 1, label: "random"}, {id: 2, label: "important"}])
const [input, setInput] = useState("")
const [selectedTag, setSelectedTag] = useState([])
```

and below that somewhere i have a function like this :

```
const addTag = (id: number)=> {
        tags.map(tag => {
            if(tag.id === id){       
                setSelectedTag(tag) // trouble here
            }
        })
    }
```

I want to push the new selected tag into the state of selectedTags which is an array, how do i push the tag into that array when i can't even access selectedTags state directly?

Answer (score 1):

You should do this way.

```
const addTag = (id: number)=> {
        tags.map(tag => {
            if(tag.id === id){       
                setSelectedTag([...selectedTag, tag]);
            }
        })
}
```

this could be another way to do the same job.

```
const addTag = (id: number)=> {
  let tag = tags.find(tag => tag.id === id);
  setSelectedTag([...selectedTag, tag]);
}
```

Comment: I'm actually using typescript so im getting `Type '{ id: number; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.` error. It says that `const selectedTag[] : never`

EDIT: Fixed it. Just had to add a type to the selectedTag state.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript this should help you

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.Filter or Array.find for get selected tag

Example for your code:

```
const addTag = (id: number)=> {
  const filteredTag =  tags.find(tag => tag.id === id))
   setSelectedTag(filteredTag);
    }
```

find return object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const addTag = (id: number)=> {
        tags.map(tag => {
            if(tag.id === id){
const tags = [...selectedTag];
tags.push(tag);   
                setSelectedTag(tags);
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See useState reference at [useState hooks API reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

useState does not automatically merge values, However you can mimic it as follows,
Warning : following code is not tested.

```
const addTag = (id: number)=> {
        tags.map(tag => {
            if(tag.id === id){       
                setSelectedTag([... selectedTag],...[tag])
            }
        })
    }
```

Edit:
In order to have clean code following will work better. Which is basically same as @amruth.
Above code will be better useful if you are merging two arrays.

```
setSelectedTag([... selectedTag, tag])
```