# Cannot create list of Promise objects with for loop and push() method

Tags: typescript

I was trying to populate some test data in the database, in my Typescript / Typeorm backend project:

```
const createEntity = async <T extends EntityConstructor>(
  Constructor: T,
  input: Partial<InstanceType<T>>,
): Promise<InstanceType<T>> => {
  const instance = Constructor.create(input);
  return validateAndSaveEntity(instance as InstanceType<T>);
};


const seedIssues = (): Promise<Issue[]> => {

  const issues = [
    createEntity(Issue, {
      title: 'Case 1'
    }),
    createEntity(Issue, {
      title: 'Case 2'
    }),

    ...

  ];

  return Promise.all(issues);
};
```

The above works, but obviously I don't want to write a long long list containing the items. So I switched to using a for loop and append the items to the list:

```
const seedIssues = (): Promise<Issue[]> => {
  let issues = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    issues.push(
      createEntity(Issue, {
        title: 'Case ' + String(i),
      })
    )
  }

  return Promise.all(issues);
};
```

However, this code does not work and it throws this error:

```
src/database/createGuestAccount2.ts:172:7 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise<Issue>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

172       createEntity(Issue, {
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
173         title: 'Case ' + String(i),
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
181       })
    ~~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (/Users/api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:293:12)
    at reportTSError (/Users/api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:297:19)
    at getOutput (/Users/api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:399:34)
    at Object.compile (/Users/api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:457:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:530:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:533:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
```

What does it mean? How can I proceed to create many test data points with the for loop?

Comment: _Where_ is that error? If it's on the push, did you try specifying the type of the issues array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "not assignable to parameter of type never" error in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the issues variable a type when you declare it:

```js
const seedIssues = (): Promise<Issue[]> => {
  let issues: Promise<Issue>[] = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    issues.push(
      createEntity(Issue, {
        title: 'Case ' + String(i),
      })
    )
  }

  return Promise.all(issues);
};
```

Comment: silly me! I was trying `let issues: Promise<Issue[]> = []`

Comment: Yeah, it's multiple promises and not one promise with multiple issues. The small things o.o