# I'm new to Angular, I'm trying to figure out where I'm wrong

Tags: angular, typescript

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure what to do?[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ3Xo.png

Comment: Add a type to `cartItems`: `cartItems: Product[] = [];` And: please do not post images of code.

Comment: please add code and error to OP

Comment: `[]` is inferred as `never[]`, so you have to add a type like @pzaenger suggested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "not assignable to parameter of type never" error in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript)

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try to be better, @pzaenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should type the array

```
private cartItems = [] as Product[];
```

per typescript eslint default rules
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/prefer-as-const.md

Comment: I would prefer pzaenger's suggested syntax: `cartItems: Product[] = [];`