# How to Solve " Property 'item' does not exist on type 'never'. " in Angular by TypeScript the Code is below

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, frontend

```
addToCart (event: any) {
    if ("cart" in localStorage) {
      this.cartProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")!)
      console.log(event);
      let exist = this.cartProducts.find(item => item.item.id == event.item.id);
      if(exist) {
        alert("This product is already in your cart");
      } else {
        this.cartProducts.push(event);
        localStorage.setItem("cart" , JSON.stringify(this.cartProducts));
      }
    }else {
      this.cartProducts.push(event);
      localStorage.setItem("cart" , JSON.stringify(this.cartProducts));
    }    
  }
```

`your text`

I tried to solve it with type annotation but I couldn't.
And there is no any quick fix to fix this problem.

Comment: try *item?.item?.id == event?.item?.id*

Comment: Show how you declare `cartProducts`.

Comment: Fairly certain this'll be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript

Comment: Sorry for being picky, but if you would use typescript properly since it's already enforced by the framework you are using and you would never face that issue. Just define types/interfaces for the variables that you are operating with and you will love how intellisence will guide you forward

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not typing `cartProducts` and this starts out as an empty array.

```
cartProducts = []
```

This defaults as type `never[]`. See [What is "not assignable to parameter of type never" error in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript)

You should type this

```
cartProducts: ICartProduct[] = []
```

`any` is a type to avoid. The purpose of typescript is to catch errors and `any` will never do that for you.