# Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, axios, tsx

Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type

```
'{ login: string; id: number; node_id: string; avatar_url: string; url: string; }': login, id, node_id, avatar_url, url
```

I was creating a component that take an ApiUrl and fetch info by axios then set state for useState User and after that i can use that information to do destructurization and use that variables in html

[image]
[image]

Comment: please paste your code in question!

Comment: Also, don't repeat yourself just to meet the minimum number of characters.

Comment: `userInfo` is an array. You are trying to destructure an array as if it were an object.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when you define the `userInfo` variable. You are using the following code:

```js
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState([]);
```

Often when we write TypeScript, we take advantage of the powerful compiler. It will implicitly type variables upon declaration. This can be useful when you initialize a variable with a `string`, `number`, `boolean`, or a prototype/class constructor. The downside to this is that, oftentimes, we assign a variable, but never check what data type TypeScript implicitly assigned to it.

In this case, you `userInfo` variable is implicitly assigned a `never[]` type. **Why?** The definition for the `useState()` function is as follows:

```js
function useState<T>(value: T): [T, StateSetter] { ... }
```

> The `StateSetter` type is something I made up because I don't know the exact type (but it does not matter for this question)

What you're doing is passing in `[]` to `useState`. Since this array has `0` elements, TypeScript will implicitly type this with `never[]` (meaining that it is an array that will never have any elements. So in this case, `T` is assigned to `never[]` so the return type of `useState` is `[never[], StateSetter]`.

You can modify this by adding a type parameter to `useState`:

```js
interface UserInfo {
    ...
}

const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState<UserInfo[]>([]);
```

This tells TypeScript what kind of information can be stored in this array (if you were to ever add any elements).

> **NOTE FOR FUTURE POSTS: Do not include screenshots of your code. They are impossible to read, and people trying to help you cannot copy/paste your code. Include the code as formatted code in your question.**
>
> You can accomplish this by using the back-ticks:
>
> ````
> This is regular text:
> `This` will show up as inline code
>
> ```javascript
> function thisWillShowUpAsJavaScriptCodeBlock() {
>     ...
> }
> ````
>
> ---
>
> This is regular text:
> `This` will show up as inline code
>
> ```js
> function thisWillShowUpAsJavaScriptCodeBlock() {
>     ...
> }
> ```