# Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never', while trying to push data

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-directive

While trying to push data from the input to output, through push event, the parameter passed is showing error

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma12S.png)

Comment: declare the post as:`storePost:any[]=[]`. BTW, please, don't post code as images. Copy the code, select it and use CTRL+K to show formatted in the question. If you use an image you force to click the link, if the image is loosed the question is unintelligible, it's not accessible,...)

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "not assignable to parameter of type never" error in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

It is not preferrable to use any. Instead of that make an interface and import that interface and use it. For example

```
  public storedPosts: Post[] = [];
```

If you have any doubt creating the interface do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the type of your array.

Something like that if you're using any: `storedPosts: any[] = [];`