# Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never', while pushing a object into a dynamically created array

Tags: typescript

I am getting 'Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.'

I tried lot of things but could not figure out how to solve this error here

```
 categorizedToDoList: { [key: string]: []} = {};
 categories = ["BLA", "BLA2", "BLA3", "BLA4"]
 todoList = [ 
 { todo: "first Item", category: "category1"},
 { todo: "Second Item", category: "category2"},
 { todo: "Third Item", category: "category2"}    
 ]


 categorisedTodo() {
    this.categories.forEach(key => {
      this.categorizedToDoList[key] = []
      this.todoList.forEach((item: any) => {        
        if (key == item.category) { 
          this.categorizedToDoList[key].push(item)
        }
      })
    })    
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "not assignable to parameter of type never" error in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript)

Comment: You have implicitly typed your array as an empty array by using type `[]` which is equivalent to `never[]`. Specify a proper type of your array items.

Answer (score 1):

To fix an error, just do it:

```
categorizedToDoList: { [key: string]: any[]} = {};
```

But if I were you I would do it:

```
TodoInterface {
  todo: string;
  category: string;
}

categorizedToDoList: { [key: string]: TodoInterface[]} = {}; 

categorisedTodo() {
  ...
  this.todoList.forEach((item: TodoInterface) => {        
    ...
  })
  ...
```