# TypeScript error: Argument of type '...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I'm encountering a TypeScript error in my Next.js API route handler when trying to perform bulk writes to a MongoDB collection. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Argument of type '{ updateOne: { filter: { _id: ObjectId; }; update: { $set: {}; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
const bulkOps = []
for (const ticket of tickets) {
    // Some code here

    bulkOps.push({
        updateOne: {
            filter: { _id: new ObjectId(ticket._id) },
            update: updateData,
        },
    })
}
```

It seems that TypeScript is having trouble inferring the type for the `bulkOps` array, resulting in it being inferred as `never[]`. I've tried explicitly defining the type for `bulkOps` as suggested in the TypeScript documentation, like this:

```
const bulkOps: { updateOne: { filter: { _id: ObjectId }, update: { $set: {} } } }[] = [];
```

However, the error persists. I'm not sure how to resolve this issue and successfully perform the bulk writes to my MongoDB collection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "not assignable to parameter of type never" error in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52423842/what-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never-error-in-typescript)

Comment: Please [edit] to make this a standalone plaintext [mre] we can all use to see what you're seeing in our own IDEs. Right now if I [paste that code into an IDE](https://tsplay.dev/w8qG0N) I see lots of errors, none of which are the one you're asking about. I couldn't even begin to speculate as to why your array isn't auto-evolving or why an explicit annotation doesn't help. Doesn't seem possible, and I can't reproduce with the code you've given.